# laptop does not boot from HDD

Tags: boot, bios, linux-mint

My laptop (Samsung RV-520) does not boot (load os) during press on power button. But after loading BIOS (by pressing F2) and save it (by pressing F10 without any change) it boots and starts normal.
 NB: On Windows 10 this problem does not appear, but others (Windows 7, Ubuntu, Zorin, Linux Mint, Linux Lite) faces the problem. But surprisingly if the HDD connect with the usb port with usb boot priority the os loaded normally without any problem.

Comment: are you on the lastest bios firmware ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my Lenovo ThinkCentre.

Go to BIOS and this time, reset the BIOS to Default (should be F9) and then F10 to save and exit.

It should now restart properly.